# Getting an attribute price to format to 2 decimal places

Tags: attributes, product-prices

I have the following code in my **`list.phtml`** file, this pulls in the price of the product and then multiplies it by 1.20 (this works great but it displays 3 or 4 numbers after the decimal point

```
 <?php if($_product->getData('deals_bus_price')) : ?>
    <?php  $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('deals_bus_price');
if ($attribute) { echo "£", $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)*1.20 ; } ?>


<?php endif; ?>
```

Is there any way that I can add something which forces it to display only 2 decimals after the point..

I have tried `getValue($_product)*1.20, 2;`  etc but that doesn't work, all it displays is £288.492

Comment: try `echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($attribute_value);`

Comment: @plugger sir ...please check answer.. If you are not satisfy with answer then you can tell me. :) Thanks .

Comment: @plugger... sir ...if answer is useful then you can approve answer and upvote it....so other people can also use this code to solve their issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Try this core helper function :

```
// This will show a price with Currency symbol
Mage::helper('core')->currency(PRICE_HERE, true, false);
```

Otherwise use `number_format` :

```
number_format(PRICE_HERE, 2, '.', '');
number_format($products->getPrice(), 2, '.', '') ;
```

The complete code:

```
<?php if($_product->getData('deals_bus_price')) : ?>
<?php 
    $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('deals_bus_price');
    if ($attribute) {
        $attribute_value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)*1.20 ; 
        echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($attribute_value, true, false);
    } 
?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use php's [number_format()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_number_format.asp) function.

This function returns a string.

Comment: You can user number_format function for price.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php if($_product->getDealsBusPrice()) : ?>
<?php  $attributeValue = $_product->getAttributeText('deals_bus_price');?>
<?php $attributeValue = ($attributeValue * 1.20)?>
<?php $attributeValue =  round($attributeValue, 2); ?>
<?php echo "£".$attributeValue; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php if($_product->getDealsBusPrice()) : ?>
<?php  $attributeValue = $_product->getAttributeText('deals_bus_price');?>
<?php $attributeValue = ($attributeValue * 1.20)?>
<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($attributeValue);?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use this code for 2 decimal places :**

```
<?php if($_product->getData('deals_bus_price')) : ?>
    <?php  $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('deals_bus_price');
if ($attribute) { echo "£", $attribute_value = number_format($attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)*1.20,2) ; } ?>


<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: please let me know 1.20 is used for in this case?